# How to keep local file, discard change from server when pull

Tags: git

My scenario:

1. Server has one repository
2. Person A and Person B access this repository.
3. Person A add some files(file F1, file F2, file F3).
4. Person B add many files(file F2, file F4).
5. Person B commit and push to server.
6. Person A commit and want to push to server.

Now, the issue is before pushing to server, Person A have to pull before push, but Person A have to **remove** F2 before pull.

The question is: is there any ways to keep local F2 file(because Person A have a lot of files, not only F2 for demo question)?

Thank for any suggestions  :-)

**Edit question:**
The question is: is there any ways to keep local F2 file(because Person A have a lot of files, not only F2 for demo question) and in PersonA's local, F2 does not tracked by git and PersonA don't want to track this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pull rebase before you push to the server. In your case:

Before person A pushes, if person B had already pushed F2. Then when person A tries to rebase his changes, he would get merge conflicts. He will have to manually resolve those merge conflicts and push his code.

EDIT:

User a Can rename his file as my_F2 for starters....then he can pull rebase his changes....In this case you will not have a conflict. After he pull rebases, if he wants git not to track the changes that are being made locally to the file F2, he can do a : git update-index --assume-unchanged  After this is done, Git would ignore any changes made to this file and will not list this in the list of changes to be committed

Comment: Sorry for my mistake on question, i will update now!

Comment: Okey...If I understand the question correctly...User a Can rename his file as my_F2 for starters....then he can pull rebase his changes....In this case you will not have a conflict.

After he pull rebases, if he wants git not to track the changes that are being made locally to the file F2, he can do a :

git update-index --assume-unchanged <file_name>

After this is done, Git would ignore any changes made to this file and will not list this in the list of changes to be committed.

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, please update your answer!

Comment: Person A has a lot of files, so this solution may be the only one.

Comment: @RongNguyen Updated by answer...Could you accept it?